# d3js tree layout node click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, treeview, d3.js

I am planning to use d3js tree layout to display an interactive tree on the screen.

First of all, is there any tutorial or in-depth documentation of d3js tree layout usage.

Secondly, I want to control the event when a node of the tree is clicked. I wish to use this event to display more details/properties about that node on the screen. So I will need the ID of the node that is clicked.

As far as I know there is a method `toggle` mentioned below which is getting invoked when a node is clicked to display/hide children of that node.

```
// Toggle children.
function toggle(d) {
//alert();
 if (d.children) {
   d._children = d.children;
   d.children = null;
 } else {
   d.children = d._children;
   d._children = null;
 }
}
```

But the problem is when I un-comment the `alert()`, the tree is not getting displayed on the screen. Does this mean a user can not have any code apart from the one that one gets from d3js in this method? Also how can I handle the click event?

Comment: i guess it has something to do with the svg. Help needed.

Answer (score 1):

You have to register the event

```
nodeEnter = node.enter().append('svg:g')
.attr('class', (d) ->
    if d.children?.length > 0 or d._children?.length > 0 then 'node' else 'leaf node'
)
.attr('transform', (d) -> 'translate(' + source.y0 + ',' + source.x0 + ')' )
.on('click', (d) -> 
    toggle(d)
    update(d)
    )
```